# How to fix ```TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local object``` when inserting data into database?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, adminer

When trying to insert a username and password into a PostgreSQL database table I get the following error:

```
TypeError
TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1833, in finalize_request
response = self.process_response(response)
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2114, in process_response
self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask_session\sessions.py", line 355, in save_session
total_seconds(app.permanent_session_lifetime))
File "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\contrib\cache.py", line 839, in set
pickle.dump(value, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
```

I am unsure what any of this means but assume that this is the code causing the problem:

```
user_id = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)", {"username": username, "password": password})

if not user_id:
   return render_template("error.html", message="username already taken")

# stores users id
session["user_id"] = user_id

return redirect("/")
```

My database has three fields: username (text), password (text) and user_id (integer)

In my python file, application.py uses the following code to connect my flask app to the database.

```
# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Comment: May you put more information like which package you are using and how you connect to the database.

Comment: I have added the code in my python file which connects to the database

Comment: From the stack trace this error would appear to be related to the flask-session package and not to the database code you have provided.

Comment: What do I have to do to fix this issue?

Comment: I have added some more Python code

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite late but just in case anyone is still experiencing this issue, I think you forgot to include either `fetchone()` or `fetchall()`. So the user_id line should read `user_id = db.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = :username", {"username": username}).fetchone()` or something like that, assuming you have a unique user id for each user in the table.

Similarly, I believe you'll want to run `db.commit()` after any line which attempts to insert rows into your table.

And the session line should read `session["user_id"] = user_id[0]`. Hope this helps.